# How can I solve this :before or :after issue in IE7?

Tags: css

I tried to add an image using :before in css. It worked fine in firefox 4 but when I tested it in IE 7,it didn't display me anything..How can I solve this issue in IE7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@vimal; `:before` is css2.1 property which is not supported by `ie7`.

Check these for more:
http://css-tricks.com/9189-browser-support-pseudo-elements/

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: ok..I was going through the HTMl4 default stylesheet and came through br:before       { content: "\A"; white-space: pre-line } .. The br contains a :before and if I am not mistaken..br works fine in IE7..Is br using CSS3?

Comment: It's CSS2.1, but IE7 doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

IE7 [doesn't support](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t15) the `:before` pseudo class.

There is nothing you can do with CSS alone to make it work. You could possibly use a `background-image` on the `li` element itself.

You could mimic it with JavaScript.